# Design pattern for multiple view states?

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns, user-interface, view

I have an application that takes the user through a set of steps, configuring a product, say about 10+ screens.  With options to go back, skip to a certain point etc. I need to fade between these steps, and also have language switches available at any point.

I was thinking of using an MVC style pattern, having a master view that accepts a ‘next view’ and fades it in, removing the old.

It feels bloated to have 10+ separate view classes, using similar components for this task, so was wondering **what other approaches there are that I should look into? or one that is suited for this kind of application**

Comment: What's wrong having 10+ separate views? 
Having 1 big class with multiple states seems worse to me

Comment: I guess nothing, other than it feels like it may not be the best way forward. As two views may not be no more different than a little bit of text and a few options. But It would be simpler and clearer to develop I suppose.

Comment: Have a look at the stepper component here : http://lab.kapit.fr/documentation/klovis/prod/klovis-flex-core/asdoc/index.html

Comment: cool cheers looks useful

Comment: +1 @Florian. 10 or 20 or 30 separate view classes i feel is fine. Each should inherit from or implement a standard set methods, sharing functionality as much as possible. But - given that you have separate contents, each requiring special behavior in each page / view, it seems very reasonable to separate into individual classes (and much preferrable to one god class that handles is all). I've followed that precise pattern in the past with reasonable success.

Answer (score 3):

Before separating your views, think first of what they have in common.

My first instinct would be to create a View class and set the necessary properties for the view itself, namely fading between screens and whatever else you need that has to do with design.

You say the user would configure a product , so you may want to create a Configuration class , solely for that purpose. Be careful not to introduce too much dependency between your objects.

The Configuration class shouldn't know too much about the View class, more specifically about the way it is displayed.

It's difficult to tell more without knowing your project , but the idea would be to separate view & data , look at what your objects have in common , then use variables or other objects to introduce more specificity.

Comment: OK thanks, I think I'm getting my head around it - I started playing with robotlegs last night, and I think I just started to overcomplicate things for myself in this simple app.

Answer (score 0):

I have used The Gaia Flash Framework for doing this. http://www.gaiaflashframework.com/

This video introduction http://tv.adobe.com/watch/fitc/gaia-framework-for-adobe-flash/ should get you an idea why I think it will work for you.